# Revoke all AWS security group ingress rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, system-administration

Is it possible to revoke all the ingress rules in an AWS security group? Is it possible to revoke all the SSH ingress rules? I'm trying with the cli command below, but it's not working:

```
aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --group-id GroupID --protocol tcp --port 22
```

Comment: i was trying to use this to revoke any rules for port 22, but i guess we are required to specify the --cidr option... strange thing is that running the command like you posted above returns no errors

Answer (score 10):

Based on the suggestion of @kuboon, here is a simpler, working version of that script, tested in zsh. The key differences are:

- Forcing the first command to return json (which is not always the default) by explicitly using `--output json` option
- Passing that result to parameter `--ip-permissions` of `revoke-security-group-ingress` rather than as a fully-formatted command in json (which it is not) that `--cli-input-json` would require.

```
groupId="your group-id"
aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --group-id $groupId \
  --ip-permissions \
  "`aws ec2 describe-security-groups --output json --group-ids $groupId --query "SecurityGroups[0].IpPermissions"`"
```

Answer (score 3):

I ended up writing a Powershell script that uses the AWS CLI to do that.

The script goes through all the regions, looks for the default security group, and deletes all rules in it.

Here it is:

```
# get all regions
write-host "Getting all regions.."
$regions = ([string](aws ec2 describe-regions --region eu-west-2) | ConvertFrom-Json).Regions.RegionName
write-host "Got them:"
$regions

write-host "-------------------"
write-host ""

# for all regions
foreach ($region in $regions)
{
    write-host "Getting default security groups for $region.."
    # get all subnets
    $groupIds = ([string](aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=group-name,Values=default --region $region) | ConvertFrom-Json).SecurityGroups.GroupId

    foreach ($groupId in $groupIds)
    {
        write-host "Got it: $groupId" 
        write-host "Getting all rules.."
        $rules = [string](aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-id $groupId --query "SecurityGroups[0].IpPermissions" --region $region) | ConvertFrom-Json
        foreach ($rule in $rules)
        {
            $protocol = $rule.IpProtocol
            $cidr = $rule.IpRanges.CidrIp
            $fromPort = $rule.FromPort
            $toPort = $rule.ToPort
            $cidrIpv6 = $rule.Ipv6Ranges.CidrIpv6
            $sourceGroup = $rule.UserIdGroupPairs.GroupId
            $sourceGroupUserId = $rule.UserIdGroupPairs.UserId

            if ($protocol -eq "icmpv6") {
                $protocol = "icmp"
            }

            if (($protocol -eq "tcp") -Or ($protocol -eq "udp") -Or ($protocol -eq "icmp"))
            {                
                if ($cidr){
                    if ($fromPort -eq -1){
                        write-host "Removing rule from security group using this command:"
                        write-host "aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --group-id $groupId --protocol $protocol --port "$fromPort" --cidr $cidr --region $region"
                        aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --group-id $groupId --protocol $protocol --port "$fromPort" --cidr $cidr --region $region
                        write-host "Done!"

                        query
                    }
                    else {
                        write-host "Removing rule from security group using this command:"
                        write-host "aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --group-id $groupId --protocol $protocol --port "$fromPort-$toPort" --cidr $cidr --region $region"
                        aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --group-id $groupId --protocol $protocol --port "$fromPort-$toPort" --cidr $cidr --region $region
                        write-host "Done!"                         
                    }                    
                }
                if ($cidrIpv6){
                    $json = ('{"IpProtocol": "'+$protocol+'", "FromPort": '+$fromPort+', "ToPort": '+$toPort+', "Ipv6Ranges": [{"CidrIpv6": "'+$cidrIpv6+'"}]}') | ConvertTo-Json
                    write-host "Removing Ipv6 version of rule from security group using this command:"
                    write-host "aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --group-id $groupId --ip-permissions $json --region $region"
                    aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --group-id $groupId --ip-permissions $json --region $region
                    write-host "Done!"
                }
                if ($sourceGroup -and $sourceGroupUserId) 
                {
                    write-host "Removing SourceGroup rule from security group using this command:"
                    write-host "aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --group-id $groupId --protocol $protocol --port "$fromPort-$toPort" --cidr $cidr --region $region"
                    aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --group-id $groupId --protocol $protocol --port "$fromPort-$toPort" --source-group $sourceGroup --group-owner $sourceGroupUserId --region $region
                    write-host "Done!"
                }                
            }
            else 
            {
                if ($cidr){
                    write-host "Removing rule from security group using this command:"
                    write-host "aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --group-id $groupId --protocol $protocol --cidr $cidr --region $region"
                    aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --group-id $groupId --protocol $protocol --cidr $cidr --region $region
                    write-host "Done!"
                }
                if ($cidrIpv6){
                    $json = '{"IpProtocol": "-1", "Ipv6Ranges": [{"CidrIpv6": "'+$cidrIpv6+'"}]}' | ConvertTo-Json
                    write-host "Removing Ipv6 version of rule from security group using this command:"
                    write-host "aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --group-id $groupId --ip-permissions $json --region $region"
                    aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --group-id $groupId --ip-permissions $json --region $region
                    write-host "Done!"
                }
                if ($sourceGroup) 
                {
                    $json = '{ "IpProtocol": "-1", "UserIdGroupPairs":[{"GroupId":"'+$sourceGroup+'","UserId":"'+$sourceGroupUserId+'"}] }' | ConvertTo-Json
                    write-host "Removing SourceGroup rule from security group using this command:"
                    write-host "aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --group-id $groupId --ip-permissions $json --region $region"
                    aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --group-id $groupId --ip-permissions $json --region $region
                    write-host "Done!"
                }   
            }
        }        
    }    
    write-host "-------------------"
    write-host ""  
}
```

N.B.
This script cannot delete some rules (custom protocols, Custom ICMP Rule - IPv6), but it works for most rules.

I tested the script on the following set of rules:

[image: Test rules]

This is what is left after running the script:

[image]

Hope this helps somebody out there!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have to specify each source individually, for example --cidr 0.0.0.0/0 or --source-group sg-12345678.

Answer (score 1):

Get list of rules and revoke all.

```
groupId="your group-id"
json=`aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-id $groupId --query "SecurityGroups[0].IpPermissions"`
aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --cli-input-json "{\"GroupId\": \"$groupId\", \"IpPermissions\": $json}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a minor improvement to demonicdaron's script, more than 1 cidr can be returned to the same rule, in this case you just do a foreach() on the $cidr to loop over everyone.

But it works like a charm